# how to map a domain name to a dedicated url

Tags: godaddy

I have a domain name , 
By default we should map it to a IP.
But now, I have to map the domain name to a dedicated url, like `"www.abc.com/underconstruction.jpg"`

I use the `https://dcc.godaddy.com`

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can't map a domain name to a URL. You can only put an HTTP redirect on your site to forward the user to your desired URL.

Comment: As Oliver says. But if your site is really "underconstruction.jpg" then you should probably be serving a [503 Service Unavailable](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/55635/how-to-set-restrictions-on-my-website/55659#55659) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used GoDaddy in ages but I think there are your options:

1. You park your domain at GoDaddy. From the control panel you should be able to choose between godaddy's ad pages and redirecting it to another site (http). Based on the config panel you have shown in the screenshots, your domain is not parked.
2. Configure the domain yourself.

   - You can use CNAME but you cannot enter an URL. If you have another domain you fully control, you can use cname for example underconstruction.existingdomain.com and configure it at the existingdomain.com server side to either redirect or display html according to incoming rule.

Also, like the commenters pointed out, I'm not sure if there's much point in simple "under construction" signs. For search engine optimisation it's best to publish the website when it's ready and otherwise use robots.txt.

**Thus to your question the solution would be to park your domain and redirect http.**

Note that domain parking may cost depending on the service provider (service provider ad pages are usually free). Do it through GoDaddy, or if it costs, then you can host the dns at a free service provider such as ZoneEdit (not sure if free anymore, but definitely slow to use at times) or he.net.